# A relation between two properties of sequences of operators

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

We have $(T_l)_l$ a sequence of bounded linear operators from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^2$.

$\bullet$ We say $(T_l)_l$ satisfies the property "A" if $\sup_{||x||_{\ell^2}=1}\sum_{l=1}^\infty||T_l(x)||^2<\infty$.

$\bullet$ And we say that it satisfies the property "B" if $\sup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\int_0^{2\pi} ||\sum_{l=1}^{N}e^{ilt} \cdot T_l||^2dt<\infty$.

$$ $$
It is very easy to see that if $(T_l)_l$ satisfies $B$, it also satisfies $A$, because

$$\sum_{l=1}^N||T_l(x)||^2=\int_0^{2\pi}||\sum_{l=1}^N e^{ilt} \cdot T_l(x)||^2dt\leq \int_0^{2\pi} ||\sum_{l=1}^N e^{ilt} \cdot T_l||^2||x||^2dt.$$

My question is, if $(T_l)_l$ satisfies $A$, can it not satisfy "B? Or these two properties are really the same?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How is your implication "very easy to see"? I don't even understand how you can plug the single number $e^{ilt}$ into the operator $T_l$,which expects a sequence.

Comment: I'll write that implication when i get home. About the other thing, the operator is not acting on the exponential; $\sum_lT_le^{ilt}$ is the "function" whose Fourier coefficients are those operators $T_l$.

Comment: Edited the op with an explanation.

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman : no you didn't define your integral, what was $x$, and $t$ so re-write everything (note $T_l$ is an operator on sequences, where are your sequences here ?)

Comment: @user1952009 $x$ denotes a sequence in $\ell^2$. $t\in[0,2\pi]$

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman no you are wrong and do your statements A and B assume that there exists $x$ and $t$ or that it is true for every $x$ and $t$ ? so work more, make sense to your formulas before posting  them

Comment: In statement A, there is a supremum for all $x$ in the unit sphere of $\ell^2$.
In statement b, we are integrating over t, so I don't see the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman : $T_l$ acts on sequences not on numbers, so work more, make sense to your formulas before posting them

Comment: I explained that to PhoemueX above. With $||T_l(x)||$ we are calculating the norm of al alement of $\ell^2$. With $||\sum_{l=1}^N T_l\;e^{ilt}||$, we are calculating the norm of the function whose fourier coefficients are the operators $T_l$

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman : so write your definitions IN THE QUESTION ( if they mean something, because "we are calculating the norm of the function whose fourier coefficients are the operators $T_l\ \ \ $" means NOTHING)

Comment: Everything here is standard notation. I don't know if the confusion here is that $||\cdot||$ denotes both the norm in the space $\ell^2$ and the operator norm...To clear things: 
$||\sum_{l=1}^{N}T_l\;e^{ilt}||=\sup_{||x||_{\ell^2}=1}||(\sum_{l=1}^{N}T_l\;e^{ilt})(x)||$

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman : ok everything is clear except for all the people who know how to solve your exercice :-) so don't consider our advices and solve your exercice alone

Comment: This is not an exerciSe. Thanks a lot for your comments, if you want me to clear more things, I will try. If someone else has more ideas, I will be very glad to hear them.

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman oh that changed, but you didn't say if you were using the operator norm to compute $||\sum_{l=1}^N  e^{i l t} T_l||$  as in A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the family of operators
$$
T_\ell ((x_n)_n) = x_\ell \cdot e_1,
$$
where $e_1 = (1, 0,0,\dots) \in \ell^2$ is the first basis vector.

This family satisfies the first property, since for $x = (x_n)_n \in \ell^2$ with $\| x\| = 1$, we have
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \|T_\ell x\|^2 = \sum_\ell |x_\ell|^2 = \|x\|^2 \leq 1.
$$

But it is not too hard to see (see below) that
$$
\bigg\| \sum_{\ell=1}^N \alpha_\ell T_\ell \bigg\| = \|(\alpha_\ell)_{\ell =1 , \dots,N}\|_{\ell^2}
$$
for arbitrary coefficients $\alpha_\ell \in \Bbb{C}$.

This easily implies that your property (B) does not hold in this case.

To justify the above calculation, note
\begin{align*}
\bigg\| \sum_{\ell=1}^N \alpha_\ell T_\ell \bigg\|_{B(\ell^2)}
&= \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \bigg\| \sum_{\ell=1}^N \alpha_\ell T_\ell(x) \bigg\|_{\ell^2} \\
&= \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \bigg\| \sum_{\ell=1}^N \alpha_\ell x_\ell e_1\bigg\|_{\ell^2} \\
&= \sup_{\|x\|=1} \sum_{\ell=1}^N |\alpha_\ell x_\ell| \\
&= \| (\alpha_\ell)_{\ell=1, \dots,N}\|_{\ell^2} 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer PhoemueX!

However, for the second part, this statement you do $$
\bigg\| \sum_{\ell=1}^N \alpha_\ell T_\ell \bigg\| = \|(\alpha_\ell)_{\ell =1 , \dots,N}\|_{\ell^2}
$$ (that is, calculating the norm of the function as the norm 2 of the sequence of coefficients) can only be done if the function involved takes values in a Hilbert space, which is not the case. In other words, we can't apply Plancherel if the function takes values in $B(\ell^2)$ :/

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: If $\alpha_l=e^{ilt}$, its modulus is 1, so you would get  $\bigg\| \sum_{\ell=1}^N \alpha_\ell T_\ell \bigg\|_{B(\ell^2)}
=\sup_{||x||=1}\sum_{l=1}^{N}|x_l|^2<\infty$, right?

Comment: We get $\|(e^{ilt})_{l=1,\dots,N}\|_{\ell^2}=\sqrt {N}\to \infty $.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I put one more square than necessary :)

Thanks a lot!!